# pyspark on local cluster cannot call any command

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c)  to install pyspark on my windows machine such that I can practice with it. I run `pyspark --master local[2]` to start a Juypter notebook where I can run pyspark using 2 clusters on my local machine. In the Jupyter I use the code provided in the tutorial.

**initialize spark in Jupyter notebook:**

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sc.version
>> '2.3.3' 
## I conclude from this that PySpark 2.3.3. "works"
```

**Create some sample data:**

```
import numpy as np
dots = sc.parallelize([2.0 * np.random.random(2) - 1.0 for i in range(1000000)]).cache()
dots.count()
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0be12b3b7770> in <module>
      4 dots = sc.parallelize([2.0 * np.random.random(2) - 1.0 for i in range(TOTAL)]).cache()
      5 
----> 6 dots.count()
```

Comment: what version of python are you using?  if it is 3.7 then I believe it is not compatible with spark 2.3.x and maybe it was a typo but the local[2] means you are only using 2 cores aka slots from your local machine not launching "clusters" because spark is meant to be used in a distributed fashion

Comment: @thePurplePython thanks, I also tried 2.4.2 i.e. the newest release available. same problem =/

Comment: i think 2.4 is bugged with python 3.7 too ... but to clarify what version of python are you using / have pointed to pyspark env?

Comment: I am using the latest anaconda python distribution. `import sys` followed by `print(sys.executable)` returns `C:\Users\malcolm\Anaconda3\python.exe`

Comment: `con info` returns `conda version : 4.6.14   conda-build version : 3.17.8         python version : 3.7.3.final.0`